# Typecasting uint64 into double precision

Tags: c, casting, double, uint64

I'm receiving a list of bytes, in an array called "info," into the subroutine shown below. They were received serially and gathered up into the array. Elements [6] - [13] of the array represent one double precision number. They were necessarily split into individual bytes for serial transmission. The method I'm using to concatenate and convert this list of bytes into a single double precision quantity is, I think, pretty standard.

The number 0x3FE3333333333333, expressed as a uint64 type should be 0.6 (decimal) when converted to double. Decimal 0.6 is the torque setpoint for a motor control scheme.
I am, however, seeing the number 4.17232506e-08 (decimal), when the number is converted in this program.
Can anyone tell me what's gone wrong here?
Here's the code:

```
void
    put_speed_and_torque_together(Uint8 *info, Uint32 crc_rx, Uint32 crc_calc)
    // ***************************************************************************************
    // * Procedure Name: put_speed_and_torque_together
    // * Purpose:   Combine separate bytes of Speed Setting and Torque setting 
    // *  into Uint32 and  double-precision
    // *            data types, respectively.
    // *            Call assign_rx_to_struct.
    // * Date created: 04/01/2021
    // * By: DDR
    // ***************************************************************************************
    {
    Uint64 temp_word;
    Uint32 speed_setpoint;
    double torque_setpoint;

    if (crc_rx == crc_calc) // If CRC checks out...
    {
        // Combine group of 4 bytes representing speed_setpoint into one 32-bit word.
        speed_setpoint = ((Uint32)info[17])<<24 | ((Uint32)info[16])<<16 | ((Uint32)info[15])<<8  | (Uint32)info[14];
        set_SpeedSetpoint(speed_setpoint); // Using sets and gets to protect these variables.

        // Concatenate 8 bytes representing torque_setpoint into one word (temp_word).
        temp_word = ((Uint64)info[13])<<56 | ((Uint64)info[12])<<48 | ((Uint64)info[11])<<40 | ((Uint64)info[10])<<32 | ((Uint64)info[9])<<24 | ((Uint64)info[8])<<16 | ((Uint64)info[7])<<8  | (Uint64)info[6];

        torque_setpoint = *(double*)&temp_word;
        // Reading from right to left...
        // Point to location of temp_word ("&temp_word" is a pointer).
        // Typecast the pointer to the double type (double*).
        // Retrieve the contents of the converted pointer (*).
        // Assign that value to torque_setpoint (torque_setpoint =).
        set_TorqueSetpoint(torque_setpoint); // Using sets and gets to protect these variables.

       assign_rx_to_struct(speed_setpoint, torque_setpoint);
    }
    else
    {
        InitArrays();   // Clear all relevant data. @@
                        // Obviously something went wrong here.
                        // Should I send some kind of message to LCD?
    }
} // End put_speed_and_torque_together
```

Comment: How can a `uint64` have a value 0.6?

Comment: @ScottHunter Because it contains the bytes of a double precision float.

Comment: @Barmar: I don't care what bytes it contains; you can't have a non-integer value in an integer variable.  *Nothing* "expressed as a uint64" can have the value 0.6.

Comment: @ScottHunter He's doing type punning: `*(double*)&temp_word;`

Comment: Have you tried the reverse: assign 0.6 to a double, to see what value/bytes it contains?

Comment: I suspect the problem is endianness.

Comment: Hi folks,Thanks for the comments

Comment: Use memcpy to copy bytes between types. Also, you don't want uint64, you want char[8]. You may have to change byte order, too.

Comment: @Barmar I thought the same thing, and tried turning it around.
333333333333E33F should evaluate to 4.667261458434778e-62 in decimal, but the code yields a value of 4.18833643e-08.

Comment: @Support Ukraine Okay - looks like "undefined behaviour" is responsible for this one. My compiler just doesn't like the technique I used. I'll have to find some other way...
Thanks for your help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

> The number 0x3FE3333333333333, expressed as a uint64 type should be 0.6  ...
> I am, however, seeing the number 4.17232506e-08 (decimal)
> Can anyone tell me what's gone wrong here?

Yes.  *Somewhere*, code is accessing data as a `float` and not a `double`.

```
int main() {
  union {
      uint64_t u64;
      float f[2];
      double d;
  } x;
  x.u64 = 0x3FE3333333333333;
  printf("%-24a %-24.17g 0x%016llX %.8e %.8e\n", 
      x.d, x.d, (1ULL * x.u64), x.f[0], x.f[1]);
}
```

Output

```
//                       v- expected ------v                         v- seen -----v
0x1.3333333333333p-1     0.59999999999999998      0x3FE3333333333333 4.17232506e-08 1.77499998e+00
```

This is not an *endian* issue.

---

Tip: with such FP bit-dibbling, report `double` with `"%a"` and/or `"%.16e"`.
"4.17232506e-08" lacked informative digits.

Comment: Thank you. I think you've uncovered the nature of the problem. Now I just need to find out where it's getting cast as a float. By the way, what does "FP bit-dibbling" mean? I'm also unsure what it means that a number lacks informative digits. I'm relatively new at this, having been primarily a hardware designer until now.
Thanks,
Dave

Comment: @DaveReagan "FP (floating point) bit-dibbling" is assuming a certain encoding of FP objects and trying to set its bits via bit/byte building to achieve a value rather than transmitting in a neutral, say text, format like via `"%a"`.   `double` typically offers 15+ digits of significance, yet you only posted 9 with 4.17232506e-08, thus it lacked informative digits.  Noticed this answer used 17 digits to well distinguish a `double` from other `double`.

Comment: @DaveReagan "to find out where it's getting cast as a float." --> Question should have had the true code the printed the value. "I am, however, seeing the number 4.17232506e-08" is only _describing_ the result - it does not allow others to see how it was derived from this function.  IOWs a [mcve]/

Comment: Thanks chux. I appreciate the help and the advice.